# How to sanitize data in redux toolkit with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, sanitize

I got this error on my console when I tried to get the server data.
[image]

*react_devtools_backend.js:3973 Application state or actions payloads are too large making Redux DevTools serialization slow and consuming a lot of memory. See https://git.io/fpcP5 on how to configure it.*

I understand that I need to set up the store again, but can I set up sanitize with the configureStore? or should I use createStore and install redux-devtools-extension?

This is my store setup code

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
            serializableCheck: {
                ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
                warnAfter: 128,
            },
            immutableCheck: false,
        }),
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof appReducer>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass all the devtools options into `configureStore`:

```js
export const store = configureStore({
    // ...
    devTools: { 
      // options as if you were setting it up by hand
      // https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/docs/API/Arguments.md#windowdevtoolsextensionconfig
      stateSanitizer: (state) => state.data ? { ...state, data: '<<LONG_BLOB>>' } : state
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't fully understand this example. It's saying we want to remove data if it exists, but then it is doing, if state.data exists, then send an obect of state and replace data with a long blob. What is the long blob in this regard? Should we not be sending data: ""?

Comment: @Jack it's a placeholder to signal to the person looking at the devtools that this in fact was not an empty string, but something very long that has been removed. You could also write `'Hey Jack, if you see this string in the devtools, it means something big was here and has been removed'`.